# Mount .sparsebundle on a Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, bash, time-capsule

I'd like to access my Time Machine backup files using a little bash script. As I understand it, this requires a two-step process.

First, I have to mount the Time Capsule "Data" partition:

```
mount_afp afp://user:pass@10.0.1.1/Data ~/Data
```

Then, I have to mount the .sparsebundle on the Data partition that contains the backup files of my Mac. I'm not sure how to do this.

It also seems rather awkward that I have to do two mounts to access my backup files. Perhaps I can do it in one step?

I'd love to hear the best solution for this.

Comment: If you use the default setup for your remote Time Machine backup, the sparsebundle **is** already mounted or you wouldn't be able to backup your files continuously! The volume is (often) just not visible on your desktop!

Comment: @klanomath Alright, but can I also access the backup files using the Terminal?

Comment: What do you wanna do with your bash script?

Comment: I want to run `tmutil compare` to compare different backups. That part of the script works, but I still have to mount the volumes in Finder. I'd like to automate the mount (and unmount) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've configured a regular Time Machine backup onto your Time Capsule, mounting (or unmounting) the sparsebundle is not needed. It's already mounted or you wouldn't be able to backup your data regularly.

To mount the remote Time Machine sparsebundle and get the path to it simply enter:

```
tmutil latestbackup
```

(or `tmutil latestbackup > /dev/null 2>&1` if you don't want any output)

The command triggers the mounting of the sparsebundle and the output is the path to your last backup.

Entering `mount` will show you the mount points of the Time Capsule and your sparsebundle.

Your result will be something like (example listing):

```
/dev/disk1s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
//%user%@%IP% on /Volumes/%TimeCapsule% (afpfs, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/%Time Machine-Backups% (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, nobrowse)
```

The second last line is the Time Capsule share, the last line (disk2s2) the mounted sparsebundle image. The mounted share/sparsebundle aren't visible in the Finder because they are flagged as *nobrowse*.

To access your backup you can simply enter something like:

```
cd "/Volumes/%Time Machine Backups%/Backups.backupdb/%LocalHostName%/
```

(All terms framed by percent signs depend on your environment and you have to replace them by proper names/addresses - get them by diving into the folders with `cd` and `ls -la`.)

Comment: I think Time Capsule is only mounted when it's actually making a backup. At that time, the volumes are even visible in Finder. When it's not making a backup, it doesn't appear in the `mount` list.

Comment: OK, modified answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I wonder though, why `tmutil compare` doesn't trigger the mount as well. Or, alternatively, why there isn't a dedicated mount command (e.g. `tmutil mount`). In other words, I feel like there must be a more 'official' way to do it... Any thoughts?

Comment: Checking a lot of possible options/verbs (like `init` or `mount`) and googling a lot I haven't found anything better than the `latestbackup` verb...

Comment: I've looked as well, and I think `listbackups` is the best verb for when you want to do backup comparisons. I now have: `mapfile -t backups < <(tmutil listbackups)`. This will trigger the mount and put all the backup paths into an array. Then, you can easily retrieve paths to compare.